# Close terminal when closing app launched from terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell-script

I have a fairly unusual use case, in which I often need to launch a custom program from the command line, which is a self-contained executable called `./Rustlinks` contained in `$HOME/Applications`. Because I need to open this program often, I've made an alias to do this quickly:

```bsh
alias rustlinks='~/Applications/Rustlinks \ exit'
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the `rustlinks` command, I have to close both the GUI window of `Rustlinks`, and the terminal window. This becomes a non-trivial matter because these terminal windows begin piling up easily.

To try to solve this issue, I've written a simple bash script, shown below:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./Rustlinks
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  killall gnome-terminal
else
  exit
fi
```

Now, I just need to run `bash ~/Applications/rustlinks.sh` (this script) to get my desired functionality. Unfortunately, this closes all terminal windows, which is not ideal.

Any better solutions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

- The following command runs the executable, then exits the shell
- Exiting the shell across most terminals also ends the terminal window process and thus closes the window as well

```bsh
alias rustlinks='~/Applications/Rustlinks && exit'
```

- Then running the `rustlinks` command automatically exits the terminal once the application is closed!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you probably want:

```bsh
alias rustlinks='gnome-terminal -e ~/Applications/Rustlinks'
```

OK try this:

```bsh
alias rustlinks='exec ~/Applications/Rustlinks'
```

This one will *replace* the running shell process with the app. When the app exits, that terminal window/tab should exit as well (assuming that's how you've configured gnone-terminal)

Comment: This would open a new terminal, so unfortunately not.